# Reading an XML document with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I would like to read an XML document using the following code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
```

This does not work, and the following exception is thrown (freely translated by me):

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'xlink' is a non declared prefix.

Here is the XML line the exception refers to:

```
<use xlink:href="#lend13" transform="scale(-8.5,-8.5) "/>
```

How can I modify the loading code, so that the XML document will be read successfully? Do I have to set up namespaces beforehand? How?

Comment: If your XML file doesn't have a namespace declaration (`xmlns:xlink=".."`) in either `use` or one of its ancestors, then you don't have valid XML.

Comment: Can you post your full XML (if it's not too long)?

Answer (score 4):

I think this will be helpful it worked for me...

http://aspnetgotyou.blogspot.com/2010/06/xdocument-or-xelement-with-xmlnamespace.html

Comment: Okay, getting closer. I have done as the link suggested. But this leads to another exception (a WebExcpetion!?!??!): An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: The remote server responded with an error: (407) Proxyauthentifizierung required.

Comment: This problem occurs with proxy servers that use Microsoft Windows NT Challenge/Response(NTLM)authentication. When the application requests access to external Web sites, the proxy server sends a "challenge," requesting the credentials of the user who wants this access. Because the authentication method of the Web site is Anonymous, Internet Information Services (IIS) replies with the credentials of the anonymous account(IUSR_MachineName).By default, IUSR_MachineName is a local account known only to the IIS server. The proxy server refuses access because it does not recognize the name.

Comment: Please have a look, there is some resolution they have given. I read this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315909/en-us

Comment: ugh, I don't understand a single word of this... All I would like to do is to read an XML file locally, with no internet or whatsoever involved.

Answer (score 2):

if you can edit the Xml, you can fix by defining the namespace for it

```
<use xlink:href="#lend13" transform="scale(-8.5,-8.5) 
xmlns:xlink="http://myurl.com/" />
```

otherwise you can predefine the namespace when using XmlDocument

```
XmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://myurl.com/");
```

and in linq to XML you can define the attribute using XNamesace

```
XNamespace ns = "http://myurl.com/";
```

Comment: Modifying the XML is not an option, since the XML files are generated by a third party tool.

Comment: What exactly should I do with the XNamespace object?

Comment: I was about to say you use them during querying, now that I look at @Saveendra's link, that blog post is exactly what you are after. No need for me to reproduce that. I vote up his answer